# What language would be proper for http requests and html/xml parsing?

Tags: programming-languages

A few months ago, i created a shellscript that mostly uses db connection/http requests, ( more info after this text). But after i felt that i needed to change the way i was doing it to a 'proper language'. For now, i have the same program, written in perl and python. But im not sure which one is "better" ( not better, but most appropriate ) for a small program / grown up script wich most of the times do:

-DB queries/insert

-Http requests  with basic auth and proxy auth

-ftp connection

-Regular expression usage

-XML/HTML parsing

Im sure i will get some down votes, but i  need to know if im going into the right way. The main point is, im avoiding using java for now, because of the focus of this program.

For now, im sticking with python mostly because for now, the application its a command line program (using pyInstaller ) but i plan to do a gui in the future and i fell confortable using  wxPython.

So, going for python is the good choice? considering the aspects described?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much all modern, high-level, and dynamic languages target this kind of problem. You could use Python, Ruby, Perl, Clojure, and I'm sure others. It mostly depends on (a) your personal preference; and (b) any deployment constraints you have.

Comment: Since this "question" doesn't have a right answer im givin'g you the score.

Answer (score 1):

I think Python is a good choice and it sounds like you are leaning that way too.